# Understanding layouts in Marionette for Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-relational

I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `Marionette.Layout` is intended to be used.

I'm trying to something like this:

[image]

The layout includes two `Marinotette.ItemView`s: The "Explode" `ItemView` and the "PopStar" `ItemView`. This layout is designed to always contain these views, so I tried to do this:

```
var TheLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#the=layout-template',
    regions: {
        explode: '#explode-region',
        popstar: '#popstar-region'
    }
    initialize:function(options){
        _.bindAll(this);

        var explodeView = new ExplodeView();
        this.explode.show(explodeView);        // <-- This throws and exception because the regions are not available yet

    }
})
```

But it looks like the regions are not available until after the layout is rendered. I tried calling `this.render()` before adding the views in, but this didn't work. I'm pretty sure the fundamental problem here is that I'm applying the layout in the wrong circumstance.

What should I be doing in this circumstance? When is the correct time to use `Marionette.Layout`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Show the region views in the layout's `onRender` method. Code:

```
var TheLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#the=layout-template',
    regions: {
        explode: '#explode-region',
        popstar: '#popstar-region'
    }
    onRender: function() {
        var explodeView = new ExplodeView();
        this.explode.show(explodeView);
    }
})
```

Note that in this case the `_.bindAll(this)` is not needed.

Comment: Regarding the `_.bindAll(this)` i am still confused in what cases to use it and in what cases not to.

Comment: For most methods called directly by Marionette, such as event handlers and `onRender`, `onClose`, the context is set correctly by Marionette and and you don't need the `bindAll`. If someone else is calling your method, say a jQuery callback from AJAX or event bound directly using jquery, and you want the context `this` to still be the view, then `_.bindAll(this, 'myfunc')` is your friend.